# What would be a good metric that puts heavier weight on a longer time period?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, fractions, applications

I'm currently trying to think of a metric to measure a performance of a product that gives higher points to longer contracts.

For example, let's say that one contract A is a year long contract and the customer broke the contract after six months.

There's another contract B, which is a two year long contract and and the customer broke the contract after a year.

If I take the ratio between the duration of the contract and number of contracted years, both would be 0.5 and would be deemed equal in this case.

However, I would like to find a formula that gives a higher evaluation score on the longer contracted one even though the ratios between the duration and the contracted years are the same.

Thus, I would like something like

$f(\frac{a}{b}) < f(\frac{c}{d})$

when $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$ and $b<d$.

The one I thought was using logarithms like

$\frac{\log{a}}{\log{b}}$

This does get the kind of result that I want, but the difference gets too small as the contract-year increases.

Comment: How come $f(a/b)\neq f(c/d)$ if $a/b=c/d$?

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq So what I want is something like this. For example, 20/40 = 40/80, but log(20)/log(40) < log(40)/log(80). So this isn't a "function" per se.

Comment: You might try adding the two functions.

Comment: @Peter I thought of that approach but the problem with that approach is that it doesn't account for the fulfillment of the contract.... Would it be better if I add and give bonus points if the contract is fulfilled?

Comment: Perhaps find separate functions which do what you want for each of the factors you want to take into account, and then add them. I wouldn't use the term "bonus points", even if what I was doing amounted to the same thing.